# How can I display the numbers in specific cells of the table using Javascript and HTML DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

I solved a part of this exercise, taking the input from user, and `onclick` of the button, it creates the table dynamically. Number of rows is equal to input, number of columns is twice the input taken from user. But I do not know how to display numbers inside of some cells like this.

[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgp1w.png)

```js
function createTable() {
  var usrInput = document.getElementById('input').value;

  var theader = '<table border="1">\n';
  var tbody = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < usrInput; i++) {
    tbody += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < 2 * usrInput; j++) {
      tbody += '<td>';
      tbody += '1' + i + ',' + j;
      tbody += '</td>';
    }
    tbody += '</tr>';
  }
  var tfooter = '</table>';
  document.getElementById('layer').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="input" />
    <input type="button" value="Create Table" onclick='createTable()' />
    <br/>
  </form>
  <div id="layer"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

**Logic:**

In a matrix, you have to map diagonals, so if row and column are same, then one would be `row + column === length-1`. `-1` because, loop starts with `0`. Second diagonal would be `row === column`.

In your case, first diagonal is still valid. for other one, you can either try `column - length === row` or `column-row === length`.

```js
function createTable() {
  var usrInput = document.getElementById('input').value;

  var theader = '<table border="1">\n';
  var tbody = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < usrInput; i++) {
    tbody += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < 2 * usrInput; j++) {
      tbody += '<td>';
      
      if(((i+j) === usrInput-1) ||((j-i) === parseInt(usrInput)))
        tbody += i+1;
      else{
        tbody += " ";
      }
      tbody += '</td>';
    }
    tbody += '</tr>';
  }
  var tfooter = '</table>';
  document.getElementById('layer').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
}
```

```css
td{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="input" />
    <input type="button" value="Create Table" onclick='createTable()' />
    <br/>
  </form>
  <div id="layer"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try this it is another solution

```
function createTable() {
  var usrInput = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var theader = '<table border="1">\n';
  var tbody = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < usrInput; i++) {
    tbody += '<tr>';
    for (var j=usrInput;j>0;j--) {
        if (i == j-1) {
        tbody += '<td>';
      tbody += i+1 ;
      tbody += '</td>';
    } else {
    tbody += '<td>';
      tbody += "" ;
      tbody += '</td>';
    }
    }
    for (var j=0;j<usrInput;j++) {
        if (i == j) {
        tbody += '<td>';
      tbody += i+1 ;
      tbody += '</td>';
    } else {
    tbody += '<td>';
      tbody += "" ;
      tbody += '</td>';
    }
    }



    tbody += '</tr>';
  }
```